# XSLT update node value based on condition

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an xml like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<properties>
<entry key="user">1234</entry>
<entry key="name">sam</entry>
</properties>
```

I want to change the value for the key="user" tag. If the initial value of key="user" is 1234 i want the value of key="user" in output xml to be "test" or if the value is 6666 the value of key="user" in output xml to be "hello" using xslt. 
The output xml should be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<properties>
<entry key="user">test</entry>
<entry key="name">sam</entry>
</properties>
```

I tried using this xslt but not getting desired output.

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@key[.='1234']">
<xsl:attribute name="key">
<xsl:value-of select="'test'"/>
</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Could someone please help me with this as I am new to XSLT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were matching on an attribute node of the elements whose value you wanted changed. You want templates that match on those elements themselves. There are plenty of ways to do this, here's one way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="entry[@key='user'][.='1234']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:text>test</xsl:text>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="entry[@key='user'][.='6666']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:text>hello</xsl:text>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It Works great. Thanks a lot